# Not able to access resource directory by ibm HTTP Server

Tags: linux, ibm-was, ibmhttpserver

I deployed my application successfully & configured plugin, I also set the alias in httpd.conf file  but when I hit the URL it find the context root but it is not able to access resource directory which contains java-script,css, HTML code.

When I debug it in browser I found this.

ERROR CODE:

```
You don't have permission to access /Contextroot/style/style.css on this server.
```

I am using WAS 8.5.5.8 & RHEL 7

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: You'll have a better error message in the IHS error_log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pending your error_log entry, one of two causes is likely:

1) If your ErrorLog entry says "... denied by server configuration"

```
<Directory /Contextroot/>
  Order deny,allow
  allow from all
  satisfy any
</Directory>
```

2) If yourErrorLog entry begins with "(13)Permission denied"

Your added content is not accessible by the user IHS runs as -- this is just normal filesystem permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your help that was normal file system permission. We had to provide permission using chmod.